# Calculate sum of column in JasperReports and calculate on based of that value

Tags: jasper-reports

I have data something like below which are fetched by query for *JasperReports*.

The column1 has data:

```
12,                  
21,                   
23,
321,
23
```

Now I want to show the percentage in column2 for each row's value e.g for row 1

```
(100 * 12) / sum of (column1)
```

It should be done for all the rows.

How can i do that in *JasperReports*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a variable(e.g. v_sum) to get the sum of the column(eg. EMPLOYEEID).

```
<variable name="v_sum" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="Sum">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{EMPLOYEEID}]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
```

And select the filed of column 2 where you want to get the % value and select property:-

```
   Evaluation Time-     Auto
```

Example report, you can run this with Sample Database(HSQLDB):-

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report2" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="76072389-4335-4fd9-b45a-111b679776c9">
<property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
<property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
<property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[select EMPLOYEEID from orders]]>
</queryString>
<field name="EMPLOYEEID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<variable name="v_sum" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="Sum">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{EMPLOYEEID}]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
<columnHeader>
    <band height="28" splitType="Stretch">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement uuid="00bd99b4-690f-4eea-aebe-08b0cdcfcec2" x="15" y="6" width="100" height="20"/>
            <textElement/>
            <text><![CDATA[EmployeeID]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement uuid="6396c710-73d9-407f-ba02-4aceb524cb75" x="172" y="6" width="100" height="20"/>
            <textElement/>
            <text><![CDATA[%]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</columnHeader>
<detail>
    <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
        <textField>
            <reportElement uuid="dbbdb209-dbd4-4dbb-a454-32968c31ec79" x="14" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{EMPLOYEEID}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField evaluationTime="Auto">
            <reportElement uuid="f14e9e42-5486-4204-974c-c2c148ab73c7" x="172" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[(100*$F{EMPLOYEEID}) / $V{v_sum}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</detail>
```

Comment: could you please tell me what does evaluation time property do do?

Comment: is there any way by which we can do this calculation in variable ? Because i want to sort this (percentage) column based on its value.

Comment: Actually you do not need any order by column 2 , just add order by for column 1 in the query  because if the column 1 values are higher then the % value also will be higher.

Comment: I tried that, but as the column is the result of group calculation its giving me weird results in report. Is there any other way around?